# Why QDBMP fail to write 128*128 images?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, bitmap

I am developing a c++ application that reads some bitmap and work with them and then save them as bitmap . I use QDBMP library for working with bitmap file and every thing is good for 512*512 bitmap images . but when working with 128*128 bitmap files it just write some striped line in output . here is my code for reading and writing bitmap files :

```
int readBitmapImage(const char *file_name,UCHAR* r, UCHAR* g, UCHAR* b)
{
BMP* bmp;
UINT width, height;
bmp = BMP_ReadFile(file_name);
BMP_GetDepth(bmp);
BMP_CHECK_ERROR(stderr, -1);
width = BMP_GetWidth(bmp); height = BMP_GetHeight(bmp);
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {           
        BMP_GetPixelRGB(bmp, x, y, &r[x*width+y], &g[x*width + y], &b[x*width + y]);
    }
}
BMP_CHECK_ERROR(stderr, -2); 

return 0;
}

void writeImageData(const char *file_name, UCHAR* r, UCHAR* g, UCHAR* b,int width,int height,int bitDepth)
{
    BMP* bmp=BMP_Create(width,height,bitDepth);
width = BMP_GetWidth(bmp); height = BMP_GetHeight(bmp);
for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        BMP_SetPixelRGB(bmp, x, y, r[x*width + y], g[x*width + y], b[x*width + y]);
    }
}
BMP_WriteFile(bmp, file_name);
}
```

Tank's for your help

**UPDATE1**
The source image is :
 [image]

The result of save source image is :
 [image]

**UPDATE2**
The value of bitDepth is 24 and code block for alocate memory is :

```
    UCHAR* WimageDataR = (UCHAR*)calloc(128* 128, sizeof(UCHAR));
    UCHAR* WimageDataG = (UCHAR*)calloc(128 * 128, sizeof(UCHAR));
    UCHAR* WimageDataB = (UCHAR*)calloc(128 * 128, sizeof(UCHAR));
```

Comment: Post the results here, it might help to illustrate the problem. Also, the pixel array index should either be `x*height + y` or `y*width + x`.

Comment: If the problem is for pixel array index so why it is working for 512*512 images ?

Comment: I didn't say that was the source of this problem. It might however cause undefined behaviour with non-square images, so best to fix it now. What is the value of `bitDepth`, and how do you allocate the RGB arrays?

Comment: The normal approach is to write a fully black image, then a fully white one, then a mid grey, then red, then green, then blue. You'll soon see what's wrong.

Comment: Tank's @meowgoesthedog  . i will do that . should i change the library?and if the answer is yes what library is good and easy to use?

Comment: The library is unlikely to be the problem, and anyway resource suggestions are off-topic. Best to look at other tutorials and check your other code.

Comment: @Mark Setchell  its work fine with mono color test ! i really confused

Comment: Your code is correct except the `x * width + y` part. You should make it `x * height + y`. You get away with it because image is square. The issue probably is that you are not using a square image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After while i finally found out what is wrong . in **BMP_ReadFile()** function of QDBMP  when the image has size of 128*128 , the header parameter ImageDataSize will not read from the file and has 0 size . so i add this block of code to it to prevent this problem and every thing is just fine.

```
if (bmp->Header.ImageDataSize == 0)
{
    bmp->Header.ImageDataSize = bmp->Header.FileSize - bmp->Header.DataOffset;
}
```